# Why does the quantum linear inversion algorithm allow to implement $e^{-ig(\rho)}$ efficiently using multiple copies of $\rho$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

In ([Lloyd et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0401)), the authors write (beginning of page 3) that the quantum matrix inversion techniques presented by some of the same authors in ([Harrow et al. 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171)) allow to efficiently implement $e^{-ig(\rho)}$ for any *simply computable* function $g(x)$, using multiple copies of the density matrix $\rho$ *(see **(1)** below for a bit more context)*.

Given that ([Harrow et al. 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171)) presents a quantum algorithm to obtain a state $|x\rangle$ proportional to $A^{-1}|b\rangle$ for a given $A$ and $|b\rangle$, it doesn't seem obvious to me how this can be used to compute $e^{-ig(\rho)}$.

To which techniques exactly are the authors referring to? And how are they applied to get the stated result?

---

**(1)** 
More precisely, in the ([Lloyd et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0401)) paper, before making the statement that is the object of this question, the authors describe a method to construct $e^{-i\rho t}$, to accuracy $\epsilon$, using $n$ copies of $\rho$ with $n=O(t^2 \epsilon^{-1})$.

Moreover, what is meant by *simply computable function* does not seem to be explained in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this is using the Linear Combination of Unitaries (LCU) algorithm. The LCU algorithm simulates the action of any operator that can be written as a linear combination of simulatable unitary operators. A full treatment of this can be found in [Kothari's thesis](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/8625/Kothari_Robin.pdf). Using LCU algorithm, given the ability to apply $e^{i \rho t}$ to the state, the action of $f(\rho)$ on a state can be simulated. You do this by first writing $f(\rho)$ in Fourier space,

$$ f(\rho) =  \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dt~ \hat{f}(t) ~e^{i\rho t}.$$

You can already see that this represents $f(\rho)$ as a sum of simulatable unitaries. But this is a continuous and infinite sum. For many functions this integral can be truncated and discretized to approximate $f(\rho)$ well. Kothari's thesis has some examples of such functions, including $A^{-1}$. See also [this work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02940.pdf), that uses this technique to simulate the action of $e^{-\beta H}$ on a state.

I don't think that this is the technique Llyod et.al has in their mind. But the LCU algorithm is a more recently developed technique that solves the problem.